# override view Use administration toolbar

Tags: comments

i have a view that using administration toolbar. Problemis theme suggestion is not showing the template names that should override the template. i guess because its using the administration toolbar .[image: view config]. What i am trying to acheive is showing the whole comment body, when the edit link is clicked
[image: view result] , instead of going to an other page. How can i force drupal to show suggestion view templates. And is there a better idea.

Comment: Template suggestions will only ever be available for the current theme. You'll need to create a subtheme of your admin theme, and create them there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that  i need to do a custom module then do theme hook suggestion.

```
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
    'views_view__comments'=> [
        'template' => 'views/views-view--comments',
    ]);
 }
```

And then template in yout admin theme , or in your custom module. In my case in module forlder templates/view.